# how to make the view height 0 based on the content of view in swift4

Tags: ios, swift4

I am new to iOS.I will be having a collection of products.each product will be having min 0 to max 15 details of that product.whenever we click on one product,then relavant details of that product should display in someother view controller.If that product have 5 details ,only 5 details should display.Rest of details fields height should become 0.This is my requirement.I tried this ,but i am gelling an error like "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT".In console "Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x107e57de0) to 'NSString' (0x106ef25d8).
2019-02-15 11:28:51.808090+0530 PlanetZoomApp[6777:85237] Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x107e57de0) to 'NSString' (0x106ef25d8)."
If anyone helps me ,would be very great.Thank in advance.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let lmp = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LocatemypicViewController") as!  


 if let desc:String = (dictobj["description"] as! String){

            print(desc)

            lmp.des = desc
        }else{
            lmp.descriptionviewheight.constant=0
        }

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(lmp, animated: true)

    }
```

Comment: You need to do this in **LocatemypicViewController's viewDidLoad() method** or you can also set from a storyboard.

Comment: Please check your dictobj[description] is of type NSNull instead of String and because you're forcing the cast to String by using ! the app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using if let, you usually should not use force casting as! , the second problem is constraint is not initialized until viewDidLoad is called. so you can save the value somewhere and use it on internal LocatemypicViewController  viewDidLoad.

Overall, I suggest you pass dictobj["description"] to the next view controller and do the logic inside viewDidLoad and avoid doing another view's logic on the parent view controller.

```
class ViewController1:UIViewController {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let lmp = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LocatemypicViewController") as!  


        if let desc:String = (dictobj["description"] as? String){

            print(desc)

            lmp.des = desc
        }else{
            lmp._descriptionviewheight = 0
        }

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(lmp, animated: true)

    }
}

class LocatemypicViewController:UIViewController {
   var _descriptionviewheight = 0

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      descriptionviewheight.constant = _descriptionviewheight
   }

}
```

Comment: I tried this code and an error like "int doesn't have the value type of constant.".i have written like this " descheight.constant = CGFloat(_descriptionviewheight)".It is working but in that description view 3 elements are there.textview,imageview and label.textviewheight becoming zero but rest two are like that only

Comment: I'm happy your crash has been fixed, for your other problem, need to visit more of the source code.